# smbd left running after user logs out from windows

Tags: samba, samba4, roaming-profile

I have few problems with my Samba4 Active Directory server.

First of all, when user logs out of Windows machine, corresponding smbd process sometimes doesn't end and keeps showing in `smbstatus` even after hour or more and needs to be killed manually - accessed shares seem to be left open as well.

I've found this Samba 3 option that would probably solve my problem, but it was removed from Samba 4.
`reset on zero vc = yes`

Aside from increasing number of running smbds, it can also possibly lead to roaming profile error - windows cannot access NTUSER.DAT because it's locked (this happens when user logs out and logs in subsequently). Login and Logout times are also pretty high (although network and server are fast and there is no serious traffic) - I don't know, if it's related, though.

It's possible that the cause of this is another weird issue - when some user logs in (it doesn't happen every time nor for every user), two smbds are created but only one is killed after user logs out (and it takes about minute before it happens). But it's probably not a rule - I think I saw occasion when both sbmds remained active.

Any idea what's causing this? Can someone explain the process of login/logout and how smbds are created? Any help is appreciated.

Logs in /var/log/samba doesn't really show anything weird.

Samba version: 4.3.4
Clients: Windows 7